# Discrete Fourier Transform Matrix (DFT)

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis

When does it occur that the eigenvalues of a *Discrete Fourier Transform* matrix are distinct?

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of the DFT matrix are treated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors). They are distinct for $n<4$; for $n=4$ the eigenvalue $1$ is double and beginning with $n=9$ all four eigenvalues are multiple.

Comment: Thanks for the information. What is about n=5, 6,7, 8?

Comment: @user12290: It's all right there in the article I linked to.