# Cosine Summation Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry

Just to give some background, I am attempting to solve part (b) of this [Fourier matrix - multiplicity of eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117733/fourier-matrix-multiplicity-of-eigenvalues) problem from Artin's Algebra textbook. If I can prove the following lemma, I should be able to finish my work.

Lemma: Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that n does not divide m. Then $\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} cos(2πml/n) = 0$

I was able to prove this for even n. I was also able to prove it for the special case n=3, but  I am stumped on how to prove the general case. Please help me!

Comment: Hint:  Use Euler's identity and the geometric sum formula $\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} x^l = (x^n-1)/(x-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the angle-sum identities \begin{align*} \sin(lx + \frac 12 x) &= \sin lx \cos \frac x2 + \cos lx \sin \frac x2 \\  \sin(lx - \frac 12 x) &= \sin lx \cos \frac x2 - \cos lx \sin \frac x2 \end{align*}
lead to
$$ \cos lx \sin \frac x2 = \frac 12 \left[  \sin(lx + \frac 12 x) - \sin(lx - \frac 12 x) \right].$$
You can sum both sides from $l=0$ to $l=n-1$ and use the telescoping nature of the sum to obtain
$$
\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \cos lx \sin \frac x2 = \frac 12 \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \left[  \sin(lx + \frac 12 x) - \sin(lx - \frac 12 x) \right] = \frac 12 \left[ \sin (n-\frac 12) x - \sin( -\frac 12 x) \right].$$ 
The difference-of-sines formula gives you
$$ \sin (n-\frac 12)x - \sin(-\frac 12 x) =  2 \cos \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)  x \sin nx.$$
Thus
$$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \cos lx = \frac 1{ \sin \frac x2} \left[ \cos \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)  x \sin nx \right].$$
With $x = \dfrac{2\pi m}{n}$ you have $$\sin nx = \sin 2\pi m = 0$$ and $$\sin \frac x2 = \sin \frac{\pi m}{n} \not= 0$$ because $n$ does not divide $m$. Thus the sum is zero.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to finish the proof of the lemma by, more or less, following your proof.

Answer (score 1):

We have the following **identity** 
$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=1} cos(ak+c) =  \frac{sen(an+c-\frac{a}{2}) - sen(c+\frac{a}{2}) }{2sen (\frac{a}{2})}.$$

With $c=0$, $a=2\pi m/n$, so $an=2\pi m$. And the difference in the numerator is zero.

**To prove the formula**

Use

$$sen(p) -sen(q) = 2sen(\frac{p-q}{2}) cos(\frac{p+q}{2}) $$

with $p=a(k+1)+b=ak+b+a$ and  $q= ak+b$, then

$$ \frac{p-q}{2} =\frac{a}{2}$$

$$\frac{p+q}{2}= \frac{2(ak+b) +a}{2} =ak+b+\frac{a}{2}$$

so

$$sen(a(k+1)+b)-sen(ak+b)= 2sen (\frac{a}{2}) cos(ak+b+\frac{a}{2}) $$

applying $\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}$ we have by the telescopic sum

$$sen(an+b) - sen(a+b)= 2sen (\frac{a}{2}) \sum^{n-1}_{k=1} cos(ak+b+\frac{a}{2}) $$
then

$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=1} cos(ak+b+\frac{a}{2}) =  \frac{sen(an+b) - sen(a+b) }{2sen (\frac{a}{2})}  $$
take $b+\frac{a}{2} =c$ so
$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=1} cos(ak+c) =  \frac{sen(an+c-\frac{a}{2}) - sen(c+\frac{a}{2}) }{2sen (\frac{a}{2})}.  $$